# How to know what SQLite databases i have on my Android device (Galaxy)

Tags: android, sqlite, galaxy

Hello (first time on the forum),
I'm developing Android apps in Eclipse and use my Samsung Galaxy S2 for testing and debugging. I understand the database file is stored somewhere in /data/data/. My phone is not 'rooted' for what I know and I have had no luck accessing this folder through the adb.

So if I create databases programaticaly like

```
myDatabaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, "foo",   null, 1);
myDatabaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, "bar",   null, 1);
myDatabaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, "yet_a_database",    null, 1);
```

(myDatabaseOpenHelper is of type SQLiteOpenHelper)
then the device may end up containing databases I don't know or have forgotten about. Is there really no way to get an overview?
If nothing works, can I reset the SQLite, deleting everything?

Comment: I believe there are some apps to view sqlite databases on your phone. Try searching google play.

Comment: **"...the device may end up containing databases I don't know or have forgotten about."** - How can you possibly not know about databases that you've created with any app you've developed or even forget about them?

Comment: Squonk, well excuse me then :-/ I'm not entirely "developing" - also running code examples from here and there.

Comment: Mozoby, yes I tried two apps that ought to work, but su privelige is still the problem, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

The database will exist at /data/data/[your packagename]/databases.

You can clear all datbases by going to Application info of your app and `Clear Data`